# When using a thread pool, call Future#get and the program hangs

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I created a thread pool, and submitted two tasks. Why does my application hang without any exceptions after print `task one ,result: null`???

```
   private final static ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = new
        ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Future taskOne = executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Future taskTwo = executorService.submit(() -> System.out.println("task two is working"));;
        System.out.println("task one ,result: " + taskOne.get());
        System.out.println("task two, result: " + taskTwo.get());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the second task, the rejection policy is triggered because the thread pool uses `SynchronousQueue` and `maximumPoolSize` is 1, while the first task has not completed.  You are using `DiscardPolicy`, which means that the thread pool does nothing and returns you a `FutureTask` whose state is always `NEW`.

```
    public static class DiscardPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
        public DiscardPolicy() { }
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        }
    }
```

So when you call `taskTwo#get()`, you will always be blocked. (FutureTask will always be blocked when it is in a state smaller than `COMPLETING`, see `FutureTask#get`).

You can use `AbortPolicy` (the default policy), so that when you execute `executorService.submit(() - > submit; System.out.println("task two is working"))`, you immediately get a `RejectedExecutionException`.

Or use `Future#get(timeout)`, in which case you get a `TimeoutException` if you do not get a result for a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

`new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()` silently discards the new task when it fails to submit it. here taskTwo wants to get executed, it never gets a chance to execute.

`DiscardPolicy()` method internally call `void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor)` from `RejectedExecutionHandler` interface.

I have shown `CustomRejectedExecutionHandler` for better understanding the `taskTwo` thread condition.  As `taskTwo` is silently discarded so that `taskTwo.get()` method will never be able to return data.

That's why timeout is required to be set as 1 second `(taskTwo.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))`.

```
package example;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ThreadPoolEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomRejectedExecutionHandler rejectionHandler = new CustomRejectedExecutionHandler();
        ThreadPoolExecutor executorService =
                new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L,
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
                        rejectionHandler
                );


        Future taskOne = executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("taskOne is going to sleep");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("taskOne is wake up");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Future taskTwo = executorService.submit(() -> System.out.println("task two is working"));
        try {
            System.out.println("task one ,result: " + taskOne.get());
            System.out.println("isTerminating "+ executorService.isTerminating());
            System.out.println("getActiveCount "+ executorService.getActiveCount());
            System.out.println("is cancelled " + taskTwo.isCancelled());
            System.out.println("is isDone " + taskTwo.isDone());
            System.out.println("task two, result: " + taskTwo.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class CustomRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        System.out.println(r.toString() + " is rejected");
    }
}
```